# Geofenced ring volume app?

Tags: applications, volume-control, geolocation

Is there an app to set a ring volume automatically based on location? What I need is an app to switch to vibrate when I'm at home and turn the volume up when I leave home (ringing phone wakes my sleeping baby and I often forget to silence the phone manually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale), it's meant for this kind of automation. Or [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) could work too, and it has a 7-day free trial on the manufacturer's [page](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html).

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you try [llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result). Why because its free and its awesome. It can not only handle ring volume but WiFi, mobile data, run apps and many more.

The best thing is it works with Cell Mesh, so you don't have to keep GPS on.

Answer (score 3):

A free alternative to Tasker and Locale is [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) from Muzikant.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check [Just](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dvelabs.just) that does much more than changing volume, plus it has an easy to use interface.